# Are there unit testing for SQL queries, to measure if they run the same time after schema have changed?

Tags: sql, mysql, unit-testing

I have a really heavy database, with multiple large tables, and lot of indexes.

We keep constantly adding new indexes, and sometimes the old queries which ran ok at that moment, they come up to use a new index, the wrong for that query.

I am wondering if there is some unit testing out there for MySQL queries, that can track if the response time of those queries is in a given range or have suffered from a change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build a [Test Plan using JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html) and run it at regular intervals to test the speed of the queries.

The test plan on their official link shows connecting to a MySQL db to run the queries